# Python: use a local variable in another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, local-variables

I would like to know how I can access a local variable that is in a for loop and use that variable in another function. This is a very simplified example of my problem:

```
def function():
  i = 0
  z = 2
    for i in range(0,5):
      x = i + z
      print "x value is:",
      print x,
      print "and i value is:",
      print i
```

This is the output of the function:

```
x value is: 2 and i value is: 0
x value is: 3 and i value is: 1
x value is: 4 and i value is: 2
x value is: 5 and i value is: 3
x value is: 6 and i value is: 4
```

The most important thing is that I can not modify the variable i or the variable z and I use python 2.7

If I simplify my problem, I would like to have something like that, but well done:

```
def function():
  i = 0
  z = 2

  for i in range(0,5):
    x = i + z

if (i==3):
    print x #x value when i = 3
else:
    #something
```

I tried to make the variable x accessible by calling it `functionA.x` but that returns the last value that x has had and I am interested in knowing its value depending on the variable i.

How can I do this in a simple way? 
Thanks.

Comment: The indentation in your last code sample is inconsistent - that's a syntax error. Could you fix it? Also, the code doesn't actually use either `functionA` or `functionB`, so I can't tell what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think you want a `generator` for this. Might try Google'ing "python generator tutorial".

Comment: If you could do that, it wouldn't be called a "local" variable now would it?

Comment: You are masking the first (local-to-the-function) `i`, with the secone (local-to-the-for-loop) `i`... It is therefore hard to tell what you want, and what you mean by "I cannot modify the variable `i`..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
def function():
  i = 0
  z = 2

  for i in range(0,5):
    x = i + z
    if (i==3):
      print x #x value when i = 3
    else:
      #something
```

function()
In any case below will allow you to access function variable elsewhere only if the function is called first:

```
def function():
    i = 0 # this is redundant, python generates a list with range and the variable 'i' below takes on each value in that list.
    z = 2
#    something
#    something
    for i in range(0,5):
        function.x = i + z
        function.i = i
function()
print function.i
##Below will never execute and print because the value of i is 4 always because the for loop as interated to its last value
if (function.i==3):
    print function.x
else:
    #something
```

Another option would be to use `return` in your function